# How to make String pattern using 2D arrays?

Tags: java, design-patterns

I've been trying to print out the first
    word `HELLO` but nothing it just printed `HELLO E L L E L HELLO` in a single  line of code
Need to print out is:

`HELLO
     E L
      L
     E L
    HELLO`

```
    public class fancy_word
           {

    public static void main (String [] args)

      {
        //first a String 2d array using method 3
        String PO[][] = 
            {

            {"HELLO"},
            {"E L"},
             {"L"},
            {"E L"},
           {"HELLO"}
        };
        /*String VIP [][] = 
        {
              {"CAT","A","CAT"}
        };
        String COD[][] = 
        {
              {"A"}
        };
        String U_45 [][] = 
        {
             {"DOGHOUSE","O    S","G  U","HO","HO","G  U","O    S","DOGHOUSE"}
        };
        String UI_98 [][] = 
        {
             {"ONE","N","ONE"}
        };
        String HKL_001 [][] = 
        {
            {"IT","IT"}
        };
        */
       //Nested loop within math and if statements declaring 
        for(int i = 0;i<PO.length;i++)
        {
           for(int LED = 0;LED<PO[i].length;LED++)
           {
               System.out.print(PO[i][LED]+" ");   
           }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi stack overflow I tried doing this but my code is not working as I want to can any one tell me advice how can I fix this thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You forgot the `println` call at the end of the inner forloop:

```
for(int i = 0;i<PO.length;i++)
{
     for(int LED = 0;LED<PO[i].length;LED++)
     {
          System.out.print(PO[i][LED]+" ");   
     }
     System.out.println("");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much frozen extremely appreciated